# linker command failed with exit code 1 OpenCV Android Studio

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, android-ndk

I have recently tried to integrate the native OpenCV ndk with my AS project. I have modified by project as per the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#native-c). I have followed the previous steps before and it has worked fine in other projects.

Now, for some reason I keep getting a `linker command failed with exit code 1` error whenever I try something simple like `cv::Mat A=cv::Mat(2,2,CV_8UC1)`.

Has anyone had the same problem or knows how to fix it?

**EDIT** How do run the -v invocation?

Comment: You need to include the actual error text or no one will be able to help.

Comment: @phatty have you solved your problem? please help me i am having the same problem.